# return string based on integer value in django view

Tags: django

I want to return string value based on some integer value in django using view function

```
def picks(request):
    team = get_object_or_404(Team, user=request.user)
    all_picks = team.arr
    pick = team.arr[team.counter]
    return {'pick': pick, 'all_picks': all_picks}

class Team(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    arr = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(blank=True))
```

That is returning integer values but I want to return let say if pick is 1 return "Team A" if pick is 2 return "Team B"
Also the limit of counter is of 1 to 5 so I need 5 conditions

Comment: Right now it is quite unclear what `team.arr` is. If this is a one-to-many relation, then using a counter is every quite dangerous, since there is no guarantee of the order. So I think you better provide more context.

Comment: its an array but I only want to check on 'pick' variable that is returning a single integer value

Comment: @Ahmed please show the code where `team.arr` is defined (is it a field, a property, or something else?)

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I used dictionary and its working

```
def picks(request):
    team = get_object_or_404(Team, user=request.user)
    choices = {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'D', 5: 'E'}
    all_picks = team.arr
    pick = choices[team.arr[team.counter]]
    return {'pick': pick, 'all_picks': all_picks}
```

Comment: so `1` maps to `A`, `2` to `B`, etc.?